# BsonSerializer initializes class but Properties are left with Default values

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, event-sourcing

I am trying to use MongoDb as an Event store. But before I move this into production, as this is my first time of playing with MongoDb, I am trying to test every possible detail.

I am using **MongoDb.Driver/2.19.1** with **C# .NET 7**.
Basically, I have a StreamRecord class with some properties one of which is of type BaseEvent, another custom type, in which lies the problem. When I am fetching data with mongoCollection, StreamRecord is deserialized correctly, but BaseEvent properties are set to its default, even though data is clearly persisted in database.

Here is my **StreamRecord** class

```
public sealed class StreamRecord
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; init; }
    public string StreamName { get; init; }
    public long Version { get; init; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; init; }
    public string EventType { get; init; }
    public BaseEvent EventData { get; init; }

    public StreamRecord(string streamName, BaseEvent @event, DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        Version = @event.Version; // Versions of record in stream and Event should match.
        StreamName = streamName;
        EventType = @event.EventType;
        EventData = @event;
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Here is **BaseEvent** class

```
public abstract class BaseEvent : Message, ITrackedMessage, INotification
{
    protected BaseEvent()
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UseNameOfInsteadOfTypeOf
        EventType = GetType().Name;
        MessageType = MessageType.Event;
        TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or initializes Version number of an event
    /// </summary>
    public long Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets type name of an event
    /// </summary>
    public string EventType { get; init; }

    public string? ApplicationId { get; init; }
    public string? CorrelationId { get; init; }
    public string? UserId { get; init; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; init; }
}
```

The Message class which is inherited contains only MessageId of type Guid and MessageType, which is just custom enum.

Here is a one concrete event **PersonCreatedEvent**

```
public class PersonCreatedEvent : BaseEvent
{
    public PersonCreatedEvent(string name, int age) : base()
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }
}
```

Here is how I initialize **EventStore** and **MongoDbREpository**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddEventStore(this IServiceCollection services,
        Func<MongoDbEventRepositoryOptions> mongoDbOptions, params Assembly[] eventsHostAssemblies)
    {
        var options = mongoDbOptions();
        
        InitializeBsonClassMaps(eventsHostAssemblies);

        services.AddScoped<IMongoDatabase>(sp =>
                new MongoClient(options.ConnectionString).GetDatabase(options.DatabaseName))
            .AddSingleton(options)
            .AddScoped<IEventRepository, MongoDbEventRepository>()
            .AddEventStore();
        
        return services;
    }

 private static void InitializeBsonClassMaps(IEnumerable<Assembly> eventsHostAssemblies)
    {
        var eventTypes = eventsHostAssemblies
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(x =>
                x.Name.EndsWith("Event", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                && x.BaseType == typeof(BaseEvent)
                && x.IsClass)
            .ToList();

        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BaseEvent>(ce =>
        {
            ce.AutoMap();
            ce.SetIsRootClass(true);
            //ce.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
        });
        
        foreach (var eventClassMap in eventTypes.Select(eventType => new BsonClassMap(eventType)))
        {
            //eventClassMap.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
            BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(eventClassMap);
        }
    }
```

The constructor of **MongoDbRepository**

```
private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDatabase;
        private readonly IMongoCollection<StreamRecord> _streamStateCollection;
        private readonly MongoDbEventRepositoryOptions _options;
        public MongoDbEventRepository(MongoDbEventRepositoryOptions options, IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase)
        {
            _mongoDatabase = mongoDatabase;
            _options = options;
            _streamStateCollection = CreateOrGetCollection(_mongoDatabase, options.CollectionName);
        }
```

Here is the data which is persisted in the database, BsonDocument of one **StreamRecord**

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("644a86173f5ac693ebd6813b"), "StreamName" : "PersonAggregate[0]", "Version" : NumberLong(0), "TimeStamp" : ISODate("2023-04-27T14:26:31.294+0000"), "EventType" : "PersonCreatedEvent", "EventData" : { "_t" : [ "EventType", "PersonCreatedEvent" ], "MessageId" : LUUID("52B9C7B4-8FFC-7E45-88A2-585B44B4443C"), "MessageType" : NumberInt(2), "Version" : NumberLong(0), "EventType" : "PersonCreatedEvent", "ApplicationId" : null, "CorrelationId" : null, "UserId" : null, "Name" : "Jondi", "Age" : NumberInt(50) } }`

As you can see the *Age* and *Name* fields are supposed to be filled when PersonCreatedEvent is deserialized. But no matter how I approached, the result is the same with default values. Keep in mind that meanwhile, StreamRecord class is deserialized perfectly with values from Database.

Now in MongoDbRepository I have tried 2 ways of reading stream:
1)

```
return await _streamStateCollection
                .Find(s => s.StreamName == streamName)
                .SortBy(s => s.Version)
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

2. 

```
var streamBsons = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(_options.CollectionName);
            var stream = new List<StreamRecord>();
            await streamBsons
                .Find(b => b["StreamName"].AsString == streamName)
                .ForEachAsync(b =>
                {
                    var s = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<StreamRecord>(b);
                    stream.Add(s);
                }, cancellationToken);
```

Both of them yielded same result though.

I Also tried adding Conventions in ConventionRegistry but in that case moncgoCollection was returning absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE.

After hours of testing and debugging, I finally found a solution.

As it would seem, BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap() a non-generic version had a problem of identifying individual properties of concrete events during deserialization but it was able to map BaseEvent properties just fine. Generic version of this method worked perfectly, but I wanted to have a more general approach, I wanted my code to register class maps automatically according to passed assemblies without tediously registering every single event. So after a little while, I found that registering class maps like so did the trick:

```
private static void InitializeBsonClassMaps(IEnumerable<Assembly> eventsHostAssemblies)
{
    var eventTypes = eventsHostAssemblies
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(x =>
            x.Name.EndsWith("Event", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            && x.BaseType == typeof(BaseEvent)
            && x.IsClass)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var eventClassMap in eventTypes.Select(eventType =>
                 new BsonClassMap(eventType, new BsonClassMap(typeof(BaseEvent)))))
    {
        eventClassMap.AutoMap();
        eventClassMap.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(eventClassMap);
    }
}
```

Two things I added here:

1. AutoMap();
2. Register BaseEvent class map for every event.

Not really sure which one cut the deal, but it works now.